Option to migrate to Ethereum SE, Monero SE and IOTA SE
Lots of questions belong to these subs. It'd allow these questions to be answered.

I do see the option to "close as off-topic" > "this question belongs on another site" > text field to put which one. Are you sure that it's not just that the question is older than 6 months? Questions older than 6 months cannot be migrated to other network sites.

@Murch I think that text field is only for moderators

I think Ethereum would be a good candidate for a migration.
There is no ripple SE site, perhaps you meant Monero? Note that Monero is still in Beta and thus can't be added as a migration unfortunately.
Another good migration would be to crypto.SE in my opinion
