Proposed Timeline for Scope Change
Following up from the proposal to change the Bitcoin stackexchange's scope and the proposed help center text, we propose that the scope change occur on Monday July 1st.
This scope change will result in:

changes to the help center text indicating the new scope
a new off topic close reason
editing altcoin related tags to note that they are no longer on topic
closing of all unanswered questions that become off topic

We will not be changing:

old questions with answers that were on topic at their time of asking/answering


I support this proposal

We moderators perceive these changes to be in line with the explicit wishes of the contributors to Bitcoin Stackexchange. - Murch

Would it be possible to add migration options to other cryptocurrency SE sites as close reasons (for not just moderators?); already discussed in https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/952/208 but will become even more relevant.

So where altcoins related topics belongs to? There are a few dedicated SE site, but many coins exists now. These topics does not fit well to the SO site, not always related to coding. And there is no generic cryptocurrency site.

A generic cryptocurrency stackexchange can be created in area 51: https://area51.stackexchange.com/. If that gains enough traction, then altcoin questions can go there.

@andrew-chow: personally don't think now that can take the effort and responsibility to suggest this new site at area51, by myself, time and knowledge constraints are missing. But it would have place imho, a generic cryptocurrency and/or a blockchain site. I would follow and join it at least.

Finally could not resist and created the proposal.
See
Cryptocurrency proposal
and
Discussion at Area51

Do you think this meta SE site or the Bitcoin SE is proper place to announce it, in form of a question, to gather followers?

@HoZong Yes, the meta site is the correct place to announce this. Stack exchange sites do not have any sort of way to post announcements and such. Questions in the meta site are the correct way to do it. Note that we are following the example of other stack exchange sites which have done their own scope changes.

Well until now the result is only loosing reputation for me, for the innovative experiment. Not good. So I feel resistance to post it anywhere. It seems was not a good idea, should I delete the proposal?

I just stumbled across some additional text that could be changed for better clarity: 
An Eth-related question was posted on Bitcoin.SE.com, and then migrated to Ethereum.SE.com. If you follow the link to the (now migrated) question, it includes this text: 

This question came from our site for Bitcoin crypto-currency enthusiasts.

Here is a screenshot of the text in question: 

I'd propose cutting out the "crypto-currency" bit, just for clarity. 

Yeah, sounds fine, although I'm not sure that it is part of the details that we can change.

Please read my response to the help center before moving forward with this. You will need to reconsider some of the Bitcoin-related technologies you're booting from your scope.
